# Override text "Actions" on material table head with "other text" or "icon"

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I am working on material table with ReactJs, I need the text "Actions" on column head for the action to be override with other text or any other icon

Please need you guys help to achieve it

Example

Actual - First Name | last Name | Actions

Need - First Name | last Name | Other text or Icon (for Actions)

const actions = [
      {
        icon: "edit",
        tooltip: "Edit Order"
      }
    ];

```
const components = {
  Action: props => (
    <ProposalListMenu
      row={props.data}
      editAction={this.props.editAction}
      handleViewProposal={this.handleViewProposal}
      globalSearch={false}
      proposalId={this.state.proposalId}
      showGenerateOrder={this.state.showGenerateOrder}
      handleGenerateOrderPopUp={this.handleGenerateOrderPopUp}
      handleGenerateOrderClose={this.handleGenerateOrderClose}
      showGeneratedOrderList={this.props.showGeneratedOrderList}
      {...this.state}
    ></ProposalListMenu>
  ),
  Toolbar: props => (
    <div>
      <MTableToolbar {...props} />
      <div style={{ padding: "0px 10px", "text-align": "right" }}>
        <ColumnConfigure
          columns={this.state.columns}
          toggleColumn={this.handleTableColumnConfig}
          resetAllColumn={this.handleResetAllColumns}
          openFlag={this.state.openFlag}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};
return {
  title: title,
  options: options,
  actions: actions,
  components: components
};
```

};[image]

Answer (score 4):

To override the header `actions: 'Actions'`  "Actions"
Modify the material table localization setting

`https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/localization`

```
header: {
            actions: 'Actions' //  actions: 'Any text'
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

localization: {
actions: "Do",

// https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/guides/localization

```
        // https://github.com/KevinVandy/material-react-table/blob/v2/packages/material-react-table/src/locales/en.ts
        // move: <div>'DND'</div>   ,

        move: 'Drag',
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the localization attribute of the material table.

```
<Table
  ...
  localization={{
    header: {
      actions: "your other text"
    }
  }}
/>
```